# Print error using enscript with Consolas TrueType font

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, enscript

I am trying to create with `enscript` a PDF source code listing of this Python script:

```
import numpy as np

def f1(x):
    return x * x * np.sin(x)
```

however I am getting this output:
[image]

I am using this command line:

```
enscript --filter="cat %s | iconv -f utf-8 -t iso-8859-1" -v -rG --font="Consolas@12" --highlight=python -o - -M Letter --color=0 -X 88591 test_enscript.py | ps2pdf - a.pdf
AFM: scanning path...
AFM: reading font map "/usr/local/share/enscript/afm/font.map"
AFM: reading font map "/home/arrigo/fonts/Consolas/font.map"
downloading font "Consolas"
states: autoloading `lang_enscript' from `/usr/local/share/enscript/hl/lang_enscript.st'
states: autoloading `style_emacs' from `/usr/local/share/enscript/hl/style_emacs.st'
states: autoloading `default_faces' from `/usr/local/share/enscript/hl/default_faces.st'
states: autoloading `python' from `/usr/local/share/enscript/hl/python.st'
processing file "test_enscript.py"...
[ 1 page * 1 copy ] left in -
1 character was missing
```

It looks like the space is not mapped correctly to the iso-8859 encoding. I have installed the Consolas font files as explained [here](https://east.fm/posts/adding-fonts-to-enscript/index.html). I think that enscript should be able to render this file. I am running this under Ubuntu 23.10. Any ideas?

Comment: After some investigations I found that the problem seems to be that TrueType fonts like Consolas do not define a character for code U+0020 (0x20 space). I am not a font expert, but this seems weird.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a font expert either, and it certainly doesn't seem helpful to miss out the "space" character from a font, just because you don't need to *draw* it; `enscript` still needs to know how wide the character is so that is can calculate where to wrap a line, and so on.

I don't have the real solution, but here are 2 possible hacks. The first is to simply replace the `?` characters by a space in the ensuing PostScript (before it becomes a pdf). This assumes your input has no real `?` characters. For example, the `import numpy as np` line generates

```
59 690 M
(?numpy?as?np) s
```

which is a command `M` to move to the x,y position, and command `s` to print the string `(...)`. PostScript encloses strings in `()`. You could add a `sed` command to replace these "?" with " " since you have a fixed width font:

```
sed '/(.*)/s/?/ /g'
```

The alternative hack is to add the space character metrics to the `.afm` file. I haven't read up on the format but it seems you can add a line at the appropriate place, and increment the number of entries. For example, I found the `callig15.afm` from reportlab does not have a space character entry (decimal 32) as we can see:

```
....
StartCharMetrics 168
C 0 ; WX 143 ; N grave ; B 30 744 113 831 ;
...
C 29 ; WX 394 ; N fl ; B -188 -231 811 523 ;
C 33 ; WX 206 ; N exclam ; B 40 -7 392 341 ;
...
```

We can increment the entry count 168 to 169, and add a `C 32` entry, for
example:

```
sed -i fonts/callig.afm -e '
/StartCharMetrics/s/168/169/
/^C 29 /a\
C 32 ; WX 555 ; N space ; B 0 0 0 0 ;
'
```

It seems to work for me. You need to choose `WX 555` value to be the appropriate width for your font.

Comment: I just checked and verified that the space character is included in the AFM files that I created for the Consolas fonts using `ttf2ufm`:

```
$ grep "C 32" *.afm
consola.afm:C 32 ; WX 550 ; N nbspace ; B 5 0 545 638 ;
consolab.afm:C 32 ; WX 550 ; N nbspace ; B 2 0 548 638 ;
consolai.afm:C 32 ; WX 550 ; N nbspace ; B -45 0 495 638 ;
consolaz.afm:C 32 ; WX 550 ; N nbspace ; B -48 0 498 638 ;
```

so the first hack seems the way to go for now.

Comment: Interesting. It seems that enscript looks for a character named `space`, whereas microsoft provides only `nbspace`, non-breaking space. You can try editing the afm files: `sed -i consola.afm -e 's/N nbspace/N space/g'`